# Tool for converting MSSQL data to MariaDB (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

We're using MySQL workbench to convert an MSSQL database to MariaDB. However, the process takes ~5 hours, and we're looking for a faster solution.

We're using MSSQL Server 2012 and mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.42-MariaDB.

Comment: How much large data to migrate?